# null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (34, 30, null)

Tags: python, django

These are the files included in this Directory

views.py

```
    @login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
    def TaskCreateView(request,pk,todo_id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
         return redirect('accounts:index')
    else:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Level, pk=pk)
        qs = instance.todo_set.get(id = todo_id)
        #user = Task.objects.filter(student=request.user)
        todo = Task.objects.filter(todo=qs, student=request.user)
        if todo.exists():
             messages.warning(request, 'You Already Completed This Task')
             return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

   form = StudentTaskForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)

   if form.is_valid():

     obj = form.save(commit=False)
     obj.student = request.user
     obj.todo = qs
     obj.level = instance
     obj.save()

    return redirect('student:dashboard')

return render(request,'task_form.html',{'form':form,"qs":qs})
```

models.py

```
     class Task(models.Model):
level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
todo = models.ForeignKey(ToDo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
content = models.TextField()
image = models.ImageField()
timestamp = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
datestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
like = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='user_likes')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('student:task-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
objects = PostManager()

@property
def comments(self):
    instance = self
    qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
    return qs

@property
def get_content_type(self):
    instance = self
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
    return content_type
```

forms.py

```
     class StudentTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',' type': "text",'placeholder':'Enter Title'}))
content = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget())
image = forms.ImageField()

class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields = [
        'title',
        'content',
        'image',
    ]
    widgets = {
        'content': SummernoteWidget(),
    }
```

I am trying to save the fields into the Task model after form save .I am encountering the error after I submit the form. I am unable to increment the foreign key value in the table of primary ones.Following is the error

null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (34,30,null) )

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your question. Don't add nonsense like `ppppp` - explain your question in greater detail. Please fix the indentation of your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't include a `user` foreign key so you shouldn't get an error about `user_id` being null.

Perhaps you renamed `user` to `student`, and then forgot to make migrations and migrate.